# Handle path from dependency in my entrerprise shared npm package

Tags: npm, sass, bootstrap-4, shared-libraries

I have a shared package in my company that have bootstrap as dependency and the structure looks like this:

```
+ - my-library
    + - node_modules
      + ...
      + bootstrap
        + scss
          --_mixins.scss
          --_functions.scss
          --_variables.scss
          --_buttons.scss
    +-scss
      -- _buttons.scss
      -- main.scss 
    package.json
```

The idea of this library it is that will be consumed among a lot of teams.
The main files of my library:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node-sass sass/index.scss --watch --output css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

*scss/_buttons.scss*

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons";

... THE CSS RULES FOR THE BUTTONS OF THE COMPANY ...
```

*scss/main.scss*

```
@import "_buttons";
... THE CSS RULES FOR GENERAL STYLES OF THE COMPANY ...
```

The problem it is when another project consumes my library. When someone do `npm install --save my-library` the paths defined for get bootstrap are different because bootstrap it is one folder backwards now.

```
+ - consumer-project

  + - node_modules
     + ...
     + bootstrap
       + scss
         --_mixins.scss
         --_functions.scss
         --_variables.scss
         --_buttons.scss
      + - my-library
        +-scss
          -- _buttons.scss
          -- main.scss 
        package.json
```

If the consumer project imports `main.scss` file, this will be fail because now the path for bootstrap in `_buttons.scss` file now is `../node_modules/bootstrap/`

My question is:
**What is the right way for handle the paths of the dependencies of my library?**

Comment: Where is sass/index.scss? Did you mean to refer to scss/main.scss?  Also, in the 2nd file/folder structure it looks like `+ - my-library` is inside `bootstrap`. You intend for it to be in `node_modules` correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `my-library` lives in `node-modules`, use the `--include-path` option to reference `./node_modules/` which will enable `node-sass` to find bootstrap when it compiles the scss files.

Add the `--include-path` option to the command in `package.json`...

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node-sass --include-path ./node_modules/ sass/index.scss -o --watch --output css"
 },
```